# How are new badges introduced, and how often?

Tags: discussion, badges

It appears that three new badges were introduced: Curious, Inquisitive, and Socratic. What process does SO use to determine whether or not new badges should be introduced, and how often? Is there an annual forum of moderators, is it an open discussion?

Comment: It is determined on an ad-hoc basis, as a need to promote specific behaviour is determined.

Comment: They use a [Magic 8-Ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/add-a-magic-8-ball-feature-to-the-ask-a-question-page).

Answer (score 5):

New badges are implemented to nudge the Stack Exchange community in the right direction. They are designed to give people an incentive to behave in a certain way.

For example, the [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) and [Tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/225/tenacious) badges are meant to encourage answers in low-volume tags (solve questions, but you won't be rewarded with upvotes).

The process by which they are implemented varies, but they are either requested via a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on [Meta.SE](//meta.stackexchange.com) or created by the Stack Exchange Team.

These particular badges were implemented because question quality is plummeting and we need a way to encourage high-quality and well thought-out questions. Here's [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges).